# Regex that returns all words, except any text between asterisks

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression that will split the text as `\w+` would, but skipping over any content between two asterisks.

I'm able to identify the marked-out content with the following: `(?<=\*)(.*)(?=\*)`.

I tried using negative look ahead/behind statements like this: `(?<!\*)([\w]+)(?!\*)`, but this matches every word, including the ones between asterisks, with the exception of the first character before and after the asterisks (e.g. the sentence "The river *runs slowly* but surely" would match `The`, `river`, `uns`, `slowl`, `but`, `surely`, while the desired matches are only `The`, `river`, `but` and `surely`).

I also tried surrounding the original expression with a non-capturing group: `(?:\*(.*?)\*)`, which I was expecting not to return anything from my test string, but strangely returned exactly what it did without the non-capturing.

Any help would be very appreciated. I've been reading about it all morning and am not less confused at this point. I have gone through the [regex] tag here, googled, read about regular expressions, but could not put together an expressions that fits what I need.

Comment: What's wrong with returning the asterixed words as well and filtering in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match what you do not need and match and capture what you need:

```
\*[^*]*\*|(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KB1O2V/1). Use it with `re.findall` that only returns *captured* substrings if a capturing group is defined in the regex pattern.

**Details**

- `\*[^*]*\*` - a `*`, then any 0+ chars other than a `*` and then a `*`
- `|` - or
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more word chars (letters, digits, underscores). To only match letters, use `([^\W\d_]+)`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qandkf):

```
import re
s = "The river *runs slowly* but surely"
res = re.findall(r'\*[^*]*\*|(\w+)', s)
print(list(filter(None, res)))
# => ['The', 'river', 'but', 'surely']
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression likely isn't the right tool for this job. This is very similar to the problem of matching parentheses/brackets/braces (call it what you will). The reason for this is that given the text:

```
Here is some text *and some between asterisks* and some more and then * some between asterisks * and then normal text.
```

The regular expression

```
(?<=\*)[^*]+(?=\*)
```

Will give you back the text that is between asterisks. However, it will return:

```
and some between asterisks
and some more and then
 some between asterisks
```

I suspect that you didn't actually want `and some more then` to be returned, but the regular expression engine has no way of identifying that the second `*` is a "closing" asterisk.

Algorithms that deal with these kind of things traditionally involve using a stack to keep track of nesting and whether you are inside or outside of a set of brackets (or in your case asterisks).